# Jump to a heading in a view from outside the view on the same page

Tags: 7, views, panels

I have a page with an introductory area and then a view that contains a large number of items grouped by a series of known headings. Kind of like this:

```
_________________________________
Welcome Message and list of headings:
  - Heading 1
  - Heading 2
  - Heading 3
_________________________________
View:
Heading 1:
   - item 1
   - item 2
   ...
Heading 2:
   - item 3
Heading 3: 
   - item 4
   - item 5
   - ....
```

and etc.

The page is put together using Panels; there is a custom content pane with the welcome message and list of links and the lower content is a view inside a pane.

I want the user to be able to click on a link in the top panel and be taken to a particular heading in the view below. I can't seem to think of a sensible way to do this without reworking how I do the entire view/page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using standard HTML anchors, just rewrite the output of the Headings to include a simple anchor tag and in your top panel (aka table of contents) make the links go to their corresponding anchor tags.